# Получить последнее значение из строки x/y/z

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения, строки

Доброго времени суток. Есть очень много строк, формата:

- lorem/ipsum/dolor
- the/part/of/some/link
- x/y

Можно ли извлечь как-то только последнюю часть этой строки, которая идёт после слеша ? Пробовал через explode, но выходит слишком топорно. Есть какое-то регулярное выражение или функция для работы со строками, для такой простенькой задачи ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Быстродействующая функция:

```
function get_last($x)
{
  $y = $x; // На случай, если слешей нет
  $last_slash_pos = strrchr('/'); // Находим последний слэш
  if($last_slash_pos !== FALSE){ // Если слэш есть
    $y = substr($x, $last_slash_pos + 1); // Извлекаем подстроку до конца строки
  }
  return $y
}

echo get_last('lorem/ipsum/dolor');
```

Регулярка:

```
function get_last($x)
{
  return preg_replace('#([^/]+)$#', '$1', $x);
}
echo get_last('lorem/ipsum/dolor');
```

Answer (score 4):

просто найти последние вхождение  и обрезать

```
substr($string,strrpos($string,'/'),strlen($string));
```

Регулярка не элеганто, лучше уж `explode`

Comment: Работает. 10/10.

Comment: @BimBam В смысле? к стати там где `strrpos()` +1 сделайте что бы слэшь не входил, и отметьте ответ как правильный если он вам помог.

Answer (score 3):

Ваши строки можно рассматривать как путь до папки/файла. А для получения последнего компонента имени из указанного пути в PHP есть функция [basename()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.basename.php)

```
<?php

var_dump(basename('lorem/ipsum/dolor'));
var_dump(basename('the/part/of/some/link'));
var_dump(basename('x/y'));
```

Результат

```
string 'dolor' (length=5)
string 'link' (length=4)
string 'y' (length=1)
```